# How to use docker with volume and device as an action in the Openwhisk

Tags: docker, openwhisk

I have some code in docker which polls a directory to do some action upon it.
This directory is passed using -v option while running docker there are also some devices that are used like `--device /dev/nvidia0:/dev/nvidia0 --device /dev/nvidiactl:/dev/nvidiactl`

in the wsk docker action i see that to create a docker action i use the command as below
wsk -i action create --docker

i wanted to understand how to pass the volume and device info to the docker as the starting and stopping of this docker will be maintained by openwhisk.
Or is there some other workaround for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenWhisk does not support running Docker-based Actions with attached volumes. Users do not have any control over the storage devices.

The workaround would be to use an object store as the storage location. The OpenWhisk Action can then use an API to query, retrieve and modify data from the serverless runtime.

Comment: Got it... for volume the workaround will work.. but for devices it will be a problem. .. thnks

Comment: Would you be better running your application on IBM Bluemix's container service rather than OpenWhisk? This would support all of the features you need.

Comment: Will the bluemix container service support devices?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I leave a note, that for local test deployments, I have OpenWhisk running with mounted NFS network filesystems and local paths. For this, I have just simply added the mount to the source (hardcoded, could go for ENV settings, next):

Add volume mounts -v here: 
File: core/invoker/src/main/scala/whisk/core/containerpool/docker/DockerContainer.scala

```
    val args = Seq(
    "--cpu-shares",
    cpuShares.toString,
    "--memory",
    s"${memory.toMB}m",
    "--memory-swap",
    s"${memory.toMB}m",
    "--network",
    network,
    "-v",
    "/mnt/nfs:/mnt/nfs",
    "-v",
    "/mnt/data:/mnt/data") ++
    environmentArgs ++
    dnsServers.flatMap(d => Seq("--dns", d)) ++
    name.map(n => Seq("--name", n)).getOrElse(Seq.empty) ++
    params
```

To build this then run in the openwhisk-master directory:

```
./gradlew distdocker
```

And tag the produced invoker container in order to use it in the stack:

```
docker tag whisk/invoker openwhisk/invoker
```

After a restart, you have your volumes.

BUT NOTE: This is contradicting design principles of stateless micro services and probably not the smartest way to go. Re-check if you can do without mounting volumes (they are not stateless).